# Strange static cast behaviour in a member function of class used as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, casting, member-functions

Within a member function of a class used as a template paramter, I have a function containing the following code:

```
double x = /*Something operation returning double*/;
x /= CubeWidth; /*CubeWidth is a class member*/
cout << "Element after centering and normalization = " << x << endl;
cout << "and after adding 1 and truncating = " << x+1 << endl;
cout << "then static cast = " << (int) x+1 << endl;
```

The output of this function is

```
Element after centering and normalization = 1
and after adding 1 and truncating = 2
then static cast = 1
```

Obviously, the last line should give an answer 2.

If I instantiate exactly the same class without using it as the template parameter, I don't get this printout, rather I have the correct one.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Good question why. I know how to fix this, though - put your expression into parenthesis. For example `((int)x+1)`. I will be waiting for good explanation, too. Edit: If this solution does not work, then I *must be* what Daniel Frey wrote.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Nope, the precedence of `+` is higher than that of `<<`, see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: @j_random_hacker: `1 << 2 + 1` is really `1 << 3` eg `8`, and not `3`. Precedence makes sense in case of `... << ( cond ) ? x : y << ...` for in this case instead of `y`, the expression would use `y << ...`.

Comment: You aren't truncating when you say you are - but you are with the cast.

Comment: @DanielFrey: Whoops, you're quite right about `<<` vs `+`.  But I'm right about the typecast having higher precedence and thus being parsed equivalently to `((int) x) + 1`, which is probably not what the OP wanted to do even though it produces no observable difference.  It's the rounding issue you mention in your answer that causes the observable bug.

Comment: @Grzegorz: I was mistaken about precedence, sorry -- I've now deleted that comment.

Comment: @Alan Stokes Yes, you're absolutely right! I edited the code down Stackoverfolw and forgot to change the text. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely `x` (a double) is not exactly `1`, it is `0.9999999...`. Check its exact value by printing `x==1.0` or `x<1.0` and see what is really true. Or add more digits to the output:

```
cout << "and after adding 1 and truncating = " << setprecision( 15 ) << x+1 << endl;
```

The rounding to integer will throw away all digits after the comma, so `1.999999...` becomes `1`.

Comment: I think you're right, but the effect has started appearing randomly. I just ran the test again without changing anything at all, except that I'm no longer connected to wifi! Could this possibly be related? I know I'm grasping at straws...

Comment: @Plamen Cosmic ray, "relative Mondfeuchtigkeit", ... - but in the end it's more likely the calculation of `x` which you haven't shown. Anyways, just make your code safer, add more digits or allow a small delta, e.g. `(int)(x+1.000001)`. Maybe [this page](http://floating-point-gui.de) will be of help.